# Am I alone in not seeing featured meta posts?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

All I see is "Upcoming events" (am a Firefox user). I haven't looked closely at the CSS but have a nagging feeling that Upcoming events and Featured meta-posts somehow preempt each other, and compete for screen space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, my bad.

I added to the thread also [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), for which I forgot will remove it from the *community events* box, even if it has [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.

I've since removed the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag from it and edited an item in our community events list, which also refreshed the box that now displays the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) item:

[image: Upcoming Events + Featured on Meta]